# Check if elasticsearch index is open or closed

Tags: elasticsearch

Currently (v. 1.4.2) it is possible to check the [existence of an index](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-exists.html#indices-exists) (although maybe not the ideally way), and to [close and open an index](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-open-close.html). I don't see a way of checking if the index is opened or closed.

The [status](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-status.html#indices-status) call returns an "IndexClosedException" which falls more in an exception handling case instead of informational one that I'm looking for.

How do you check this? Or is there another way to make a search without (possibly) passing an already closed index?

Answer (score 9):

Use `GET /_cat/indices/my_index?v` and you get something like this back:

```
health status index     pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size 
yellow open   my_index    5   1          2            0      5.3kb          5.3kb
```

And you can see the `status` column.

Comment: Didn't know about these cat APIs. A lot nicer for human eyes.

Comment: [Here's](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_cat_api.html) a good summary for cat api.

Answer (score 6):

While the _cat endpoint is nice for humans, if you want something more script/program friendly you can do something like...

Lookup for a single index:

```
curl -GET 'http://es-host:9200/_cluster/state' | jq '.metadata.indices["index_name"].state'
```

List all indices:

```
curl -GET 'http://es-host:9200/_cluster/state' | jq '.metadata.indices | to_entries | .[] | {index: .key, state: .value.state}'
```

Comment: what does "jq" stand for?

Comment: https://stedolan.github.io/jq/ - it's a lightweight json parser usable from shell or command line.

Answer (score 6):

The most succinct way to get an open/close answer for a single index is to use the cat indices API for the target index and restrict the returned column to only include `status`:

```
curl http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices/some_index?h=status
```

This should return either `open` or `close`. We use this same strategy for index health (red/yellow/green).

Answer (score 3):

This is the answer given on [this](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/14516) issue, Which I thinks comes the closer with what is expected.

You can use the cluster state API instead:

```
GET _cluster/state/metadata/my_index
```

or even:

```
GET _cluster/state/metadata/my_index?filter_path=metadata.indices.*.state
```