# java check if index is closed in elastic search

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am using ES v2.4.1. I am looking for a suitable piece of code in java for checking if a particular index is closed or not. These threads are very close [Check if elasticsearch index is open or closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27780036/check-if-elasticsearch-index-is-open-or-closedand) [How to do _cat/indices/<index_name_with_reg_ex> with JAVA API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43006752/how-to-do-cat-indices-index-name-with-reg-ex-with-java-api), but I am looking for a java equivalent code

Answer (score 0):

I think Exists API, also checks if Index is closed.

Check this : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-exists.html

Specifically Query Param section : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-exists.html#indices-exists-api-query-params

For Java Code for above exists query:

```
GetIndexRequest request = new GetIndexRequest("yourindexname");
restHighLevelclient.indices().exists(request, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
```

Comment: Thankyou., I'm using ES v2.4, this version doesn't support RestHighLevelClient and neither can I pass index name in GetIndexRequest object